# "Pull apart" Javascript objects within function returns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with a jQuery plugin which has methods which return objects. I'm a little shaky on my terminology here, so I'll try to demonstrate:

```
$(this).myplugin({
    mouseMove: function(data){
        //Do something
    }
});
```

"Data" in this case would be an object that returns info about the position of the mouse. I'm used to working with a language in which I can rip data structures apart, i.e. write:

```
mouseMove: function({x,y})
```

This actually seems to work in Firefox (I can go on to use the variables x and y just fine), but breaks my script in Chrome.

Do I have to use `data['x']` and `data['y']` everytime I want to access these, or is there an easier way?

Comment: If `data['x']` and `data['y']` work in other browsers, then you could always store them in `var x, y` to shorten syntax.  I find it unlikely your script needs to write to the mouse position, but if you do then these variables may need some alterations to get passed by reference.

Comment: you can try console.log and come to know about exact structure of the data

Comment: @DavidStarkey: Maybe you can clear something up for me? In this case, my script isn't ever writing to the mouse position, but when I put a function after mouseMove like that, I can use data to access data returned by the event. I'm kind of just using javascript blindly knowing what it does here, but what do I call this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In stead of `data['x']`, you can write `data.x`.

But JavaScript 1.7 offers some kind of pattern matching like this:

```
mouseMove: function({x: x, y: y}) {
    console.log(x);
}
```

and then

```
mouseMove({x: 2, y: 10});
```

should output 2 to the log.

Read more about it at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Destructuring_assignment_%28Merge_into_own_page.2Fsection%29).

Comment: It looks like [the javascript version history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Version_history) accurately sums up my problem then! Chrome doesn't support 1.7, which would explain why this method (and the one I used naively) don't work on Chrome.

Comment: Yes. It is scary that the most widely adopted version is more than a decade old.

Answer (score 1):

you could do it using the only *slightly* shorter `data.x` and `data.y`

eg:

```
mouseMove: function(data){
   var localX = data.x;
   //do whatever
}
```